# Define the week as 6-days in length r

Tags: r, date, time-series, weekday

I want to create a time series with date and quantity as variables. However I always have zero observation on Sundays. Therefore I want to define the week as 6-days in length in R. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a column with the categories "Monday", "Tuesday", ...., "Saturday"

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] showing how and why you'd want to do this? I'm having a hard time understanding your use case where you can't just keep with the normal week, but changing the week length won't do bizarre things to your conclusions